# Получить размер картинки (Картинка width:50%)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите получить размер в пикселях вот как на скриншоте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var img = document.createElement('img')
img.src = 'http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/3994924_460s.jpg'
img.onload = function() {
    alert( this.width )
    alert( this.height )
    document.body.appendChild(this)
}
```

```css
img
{
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для это нужно сначала добавить изображение на страницу, чтобы к нему применились стили:

```js
var img = document.createElement('img')
img.src = 'http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/3994924_460s.jpg';
img.onload = function() {
    document.body.appendChild(this);
    alert(this.width);
    alert(this.height); 
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 50%;
}
```